# How to write custom type for array Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have interface type:

```
interface IForm {
   id: number;
   name: string;
}
```

I need to write custom `type` to store this object:

```
let a = ["one": [IForm, IForm, IForm], "two": [IForm, IForm, IForm]]
```

How to build this in TypeScript?

In result I need to get all forms by key?

```
let forms = a["one"]; --> [IForm, IForm, IForm]
forms[0]; --> IForm
```

Comment: you could check the type autogenerated by typescript for a suggestion.

Comment: What's with the squery braces in `let a = [ ... ]`. Do you mean curly braces `let a = { ... }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mapped type:

```
type FormList = { [name: string]: IForm[]; };
```

Or in case `"one"` and `"two"` are fixed properties, simply:

```
interface FormList {
    one: IForm[];
    two: IForm[];
}
```

This definition implies that properties `one` and `two` are always present. If not, you can make them optional:

```
interface FormList {
    one?: IForm[];
    two?: IForm[];
}
```

Comment: What is difference between these type? What is more priority?

Comment: I tried fill object based this type: `let a: FileList;

a = { "profile": [{ id: 1, name: "ss" }}`

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of "priority" here. The difference is that with a mapped type you are free to use *any* key, not just "one" and "two". With an interface you specify that only "one" and "two" are allowed.

Comment: You are missing a bracket: `let a: FileList; a = { "profile": [{ id: 1, name: "ss" }]}`

Comment: It is still incorrect: `type FormList = { [name: string]: IForm[]; };

let a: FileList; a = { "profile": [{ id: 1, name: "ss" }]}`

Comment: It *does* work. [Check it out on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IForm%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0Atype%20FormList%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20IForm%5B%5D%3B%20%7D%3B%0D%0Alet%20a%3A%20FormList%3B%20a%20%3D%20%7B%20%22profile%22%3A%20%5B%7B%20id%3A%201%2C%20name%3A%20%22ss%22%20%7D%5D%20%7D%3B).

Answer (score 1):

If the values are arrays of any length and the keys are fixed you can use an interface with those specific fields

```
 interface FormList [
     one: IForm[];
     two: IForm[];
 }
```

If the number of items in each array is always 3 you can use a tuple type `[IForm, IForm, IForm]`

```
 interface FormList [
     one: [IForm, IForm, IForm];
     two: [IForm, IForm, IForm];
 }
```

If you want to allow any key to be used you can use an index signature

```
 interface FormList {
     [key: string] : [IForm, IForm, IForm];
 }
```

Comment: What is difference between `type` and `interface` definition? Is is possible to write using `type`?

Comment: In this case there is not much difference, you can write using type as well `type FormList = {
     [key: string] : [IForm, IForm, IForm];
 }`

Comment: Mustumesc mult! :)